# Windows 7: Black screen after update?

Tags: windows-7, display, updates

I just restarted my new laptop to install updates, and while installing the updates during the startup the screen suddenly went black! I tried restarting it, but i keep getting back to the black screen after the Windows 7 progressbar (the one you see when you boot up).

I never reach the login screen.

I also think the updates were interrupted because it never finished updating all 300 000 updates (yes, that's an insane amount of updates!).

Any solutions?

---

Update!

While waiting for an answer here i left the computer on with the black screen.. and suddenly the startup repair popped up out of nowhere! It's currently attempting to fix the problems. I'll update afterwards.

Comment: Try safe mode....Why did you even attempt to allow 300,000 updates to be installed?

Comment: I didn't! It's actually not even my computer, it's my grandmothers. I just came over to help her with some stuff, and it started updating as soon as i turned it on.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is go to safe mode restart your computer hit f8 choose safe mode see if that loads. If it manages to load your window go to the the system restore and see if you go back to the previous point before the update. Go to start/programs/accessories/system tools ---> choose system restore it will provide you to the previous restore point that should help fix this problem since it's related to your windows update.

good luck